# try to create an account Using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, webservices

I don't understand why I have an error when I run the create request trough SoapUi.
Here my code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D58000000OyHZ!AR0AQI9g4KzbEYG8WrQ46aIncIqhSU6HQ3_8qR1qQjGq7YdqKBW5qCvFnkjup3gP0fgqP5_2bpxE8qYuHn.cneQKjwj50yvU</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:create>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <Name>Bluebeards Grog House</Name>
            <Description>It is better than Blackbeards</Description>
         </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:create>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and here the error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode>
         <faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue you need to add a new end point to your SOAP request in SoapUI.

Use the URL present in `<serverUrl>` element in the Login response. This will fix your issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the actual request, but with the URL that you're sending the request to.

When you make SOAP login() call, you receive response similar to (shortened for readability):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse>
            <result>
                ....
                <serverUrl>https://subdomain.cs81.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0/00D2600000011**</serverUrl>
                ...
            </result>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

You should use this `serverUrl` to make your next SOAP calls.

Comment: This helped me! :)